# macOS High Sierra Toolbar within window Blending Mode problem

Tags: swift, macos

Why does the toolbar in NSWindowController apply a different way on macOS Catalina and macOS High Sierra?

For example, on macOS Catalina, the blending mode is smooth without any problems.

However, in High Sierra, the blending mode remains smooth, only when I scroll from bottom to top and the content in the viewController fills the Toolbar, it still runs smoothly with the color changing according to the color of the content, however, when I scroll back from top to bottom Until the content in the toolbar is empty, the windowFrame in this case the toolbar still displays the last color or the color in the topmost content in the viewController.

For example, when making a selection in the tableview, if you select the top row, then scroll, the blue color will always be in the toolbar frame after scrolling down again. If you select the line below or not the top line, the toolbar frame will clear to blue as you scroll. How to overcome this

```
override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        self.window?.delegate = self
        if let windowFrameData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "WindowFrame"),
           let windowFrame = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSValue.self, from: windowFrameData) {
            // Mendapatkan ukuran dan posisi jendela dari data yang disimpan
            let frame = windowFrame.rectValue
            
            // Mengatur ulang ukuran dan posisi jendela
            self.window?.setFrame(frame, display: true)
        } else {
            // Jika tidak ada ukuran yang disimpan, gunakan ukuran default di sini.
            let defaultSize = NSSize(width: 1280, height: 720)
            self.window?.setContentSize(defaultSize)
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSWindow.didResizeNotification, object: self.window, queue: nil) { notification in
            if let window = notification.object as? NSWindow {
                _ = window.frame.size
                do {
                    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: NSValue(rect: window.frame), requiringSecureCoding: false)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "WindowFrame")
                } catch {
                    print("Error archiving window frame: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSWindow.didMoveNotification, object: self.window, queue: nil) { notification in
            if let window = notification.object as? NSWindow {
                let newPosition = window.frame.origin
                do {
                    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: NSValue(point: newPosition), requiringSecureCoding: false)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "WindowFrame")
                } catch {
                    print("Error archiving window position: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) { [weak self] (event) -> NSEvent? in
            return self?.handleKeyEvent(event: event) ?? event
        }
        if let splitViewController = self.contentViewController as? SplitVC {
            delegate = splitViewController
        }
}
```

Comment: Answer to "why does the toolbar in NSWindowController apply a different way on macOS Catalina and macOS High Sierra": Because Apple keeps changing the look.

Comment: What is your question, how to overcome what on which OS?

Comment: My Question is, how to make toolbar blending works smooth on   both OS.

Comment: Just like on Catalina.

Answer (score -1):

Just make windowController as FullSizeContentView, then window blending work again in High Sierra. –

Comment: This answer would be much better if you posted some relevant code showing how to implement your suggested solution.